# Show that $B⊂A$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A=Ψ^{r}×T$ and $B=Ψ^{m}×T$ where $Ψ$ is an infinite discrete set and $T$ is a finite set of real numbers. Assume that $m≤r$.

My **question** is: Show that $B⊂A$

Comment: @DanZimm: In proving the inclusion.

Comment: The inclusion is not true. For example, $\mathbb{Z}\times\{0\} \not\subseteq \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\times\{0\}$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese what element is in $\mathbb{Z} \times \{0\}$ that's not in $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \times \{0\}$?

Comment: @DanZimm: All of them.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese if we consider $(1,0)$ to be similar to $(0,1,0)$, i.e. extending the vector by a zero then it holds, however only if $0 \in \Psi$ in this case then.

Comment: @DanZimm: If you do that, then there is a bijection between $\mathbb{Z}\times\{0\}$ and a subset of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\times\{0\}$, but that is not the same thing as saying $\mathbb{Z}\times\{0\} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\times\{0\}$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese ah fair enough, I was trying to rationalize in some topological sense (i.e. let's work in the bigger space and take elements in the smaller space), but that would require to work with $\underbrace{\{0\}\times\{0\}\times\ldots}_{r-m \; 0's} \times \Psi^m \times T$ as $B$, not what he stated.

Comment: @DanZimm: Does your last operation define a bijection?

Comment: @DER was that a question or a statement?

Comment: @DanZimm: It is a question.

Comment: @DER it depends how you define the function (what the domain is, the codomain).

Comment: @DanZimm: All the sets are real.

Comment: @DER the short answer is no, you cannot construct a bijection, check my answer for more information

Comment: @DanZimm: But  Michael Albanese talk about a bijection in the sven comment of this post.

Comment: @DER check my answer, the surjective part fails

Comment: @DanZimm: Thank you very much.

Comment: @DanZimm: What you mean by this sentence in your answer: We don't have surjection if $r>m$ clearly since $ψ0$ will indeed **be necessary then**. The question is about be necessary then.

Comment: @DER discuss on my question

Comment: @DanZimm: No, on your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been said in the comments this inclusion does not hold. If instead you work with
$$
B = \underbrace{\{0\}\times\{0\}\times\ldots}_{r-m \; 0's} \times \Psi^m \times T
$$
and the property that $0 \in \Psi$ then we can construct a proof as follows:

Let $b \in B$. I intend to show that $b \in A$ thus proving $B \subset A$.

Now we know that $b = (\underbrace{0,0,\ldots}_{r-m \; 0's},\psi_1, \psi_2, \ldots, \psi_m, t)$ where $\psi_i \in \Psi$ and $t \in T$. Since $0 \in \Psi$ we then have that $b \in A$.

Now if you wanted to construct an injection from $\phi : B \to A$ with the definitions of $A,B$ as were originally asked, then you could do so as follows:

Pick some $\psi_0 \in \Psi$ and put
$$
\phi(\psi_1,\psi_2,\ldots,\psi_m,t) = (\underbrace{\psi_0,\psi_0,\ldots}_{r-m \; \psi_0's},\psi_1,\psi_2,\ldots,\psi_m,t)
$$
then indeed we have $\phi(\mathbf{x}) = \phi(\mathbf{y}) \implies \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{y}$. We don't have surjection if $r > m$ clearly since $\psi_0$ will indeed be necessary then.

However you can construct an surjection $\rho : A \to B$ where
$$
\rho(\psi_1,\psi_2,\ldots,\psi_r,t) = (\psi_1,\psi_2,\ldots,\psi_m,t)
$$
This is clearly surjective since we can range over all of $T$ and all of $\Psi$ in the first $m \; \psi_i$. It is not injective since clearly for $i > m$ we can have an infinite number of $\psi_i$ which all map to the same elements.

Comment: By $\psi_0$ will indeed by necessary then I mean that we will need to create a vector by with at least 1 $\psi_0$ in it.

Comment: @  DanZimm: Ok it is clear now. Thank you.